Find the number of ways using generating function - Answer check
Solve the following using generating function:
Antonio wants to make a cup cake with the following restrictions. The number of packets of baking soda must be even number. The number of chocolate pieces must be a multiple of 4, there can be at most four strawberries and exactly one sugar cube.
If 6 ingredients are used in total, then how many ways can Antonio do so?
My try:
Generating function for baking soda: $1+x^2+ x^4+x^6+....$
Generating function for chocolate piece: $1+x^4+x^8+....$
Generating function for baking soda: $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4$
Generating function for sugar cube: $x$
Hence we need to find the coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1+x^2+ x^4+x^6+....)(1+x^4+x^8+....)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(x)$ which is equivalent  to find the coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+x^2+ x^4+x^6+....)(1+x^4+x^8+....)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$.
Now, if we multiply $(1+x^4+x^8+....)(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)$ we get $((1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)+(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)+\cdots)$
Now $((1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)+(x^4+x^5+x^6+x^7+x^8)+\cdots)=1+x+x^2+x^3+2x^4+x^5+x^6+\cdots$
Now if we multiply $(1+x^2+ x^4+x^6+....)$ with $(1+x+x^2+x^3+2x^4+x^5+x^6+\cdots)$, we find that we get $x^5$ in the following ways:

$x^2 \times x^3=x^5$
$1.x^5=x^5$

Thus the co-efficient of $x^5$ is 2, thus the answer is $2$. Is it correct?
I would be grateful if someone could check if the answer is correct. If it is not correct, please let me know  in which step I am going wrong.

Seems like overkill for such small numbers.  Should be easy to just write it out explicitly...if you only see $2$ solutions, what are they?  Worth noting:  the rules are not clear.  Can you omit ingredients?  If so, then you must have either $0$ or $4$ pieces of chocolate.  I'd work from there.

Should say:  even if you are somehow required to use these methods, you should still do it explicitly.  That way you will at least be sure of the right answer and you'll have a complete list of the cases which you can use to check whatever other method you use.

@Lulu;can you please help where I am wrong

You can do that yourself.  Writing out all possible solutions only takes a few seconds, and then you'll know.

And, again, the rules are not clear.  It seems there are no solutions that use all $4$ ingredients, so I guess $0$ is allowed?  Doesn't really make sense...you can bake without chocolate but without baking soda?   Of course, for a math problem you can assume whatever you want.  What matters is that you make your assumptions clear and explicit.

Yes, I was just about to ask: are $0$ ingredients allowed, e.g. presumably it seems like a chocolate cake, so $0$ chocolate ?And can you make any cake with no baking soda ??? Pl. clarify.

You will also have $x^4.x$ which adds $1$ to your answer.
